# Why does my fetch function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, undefined, youtube-data-api

I'm making a chrome extension where I'm calling the youtube API and using fetch() to do so. I don't understand why I'm getting an undefined variable when I call the function. Here is where I'm calling the function;

```
document.querySelector("[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function() {
    //console.log("this was clicked");
    let videoId = document.getElementById('vidUrl').value;
    videoId = videoId.substring(videoId.indexOf('=') + 1);
    console.log(videoId);
    //chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "startFunc", vidId: videoId});
    let request = addToQueue(videoId);
    console.log(request);
    console.log(request.snippet.title);
    let table = document.querySelector(".table");
    let row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    let title = row.insertCell(0);
    let author = row.insertCell(1);
    title.innerHTML = request.Data.snippet.title;
    author.innerHTML = request.Data.snippet.videoOwnerChannelTitle;
})
```

and this is the function itself;

```
function addToQueue(vidId){
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
      //console.log(token);      
      let fetchString = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      let post = 
      {
        "part": [
          "snippet"
        ],
        "id": "UC0E5pDp_c2riLV4UhEgynKA",
          "snippet": {
            "playlistId": "PLu4fFFN_062GzqARIz3gnERiJ8M4GbRcL",
            "position": 1,
            "resourceId": {
              "kind": "youtube#video",
              "videoId": vidId
            }
        }
      }
      let fetchOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post),
      }
      fetch(fetchString,fetchOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          //console.log(typeof data);
          //chrome.runtime.sendMessage({Data : data});
          return data;
      });
    })
  }
```

I'm fairly new to javascript and chrome extensions so please forgive me if this is something obvious.

Comment: are you getting undefined in that console log? or from the output of running the method?

Comment: @about14sheep there is 2 console.logs I'm getting an undefined in the one where I'm calling the method and in the actual fetch method it's returning the JSON. It is also undefined from the output of running the method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you not returning anything from the `addToQueue` function. This will always return `undefined`. The return statement you are using returns from the callback, but not the function itself.

Update your method and put a return in front of the fetch call, like this:

```
async function addToQueue(vidId){
    return chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, async function (token) {
      //console.log(token);      
      let fetchString = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      let post = 
      {
        "part": [
          "snippet"
        ],
        "id": "UC0E5pDp_c2riLV4UhEgynKA",
          "snippet": {
            "playlistId": "PLu4fFFN_062GzqARIz3gnERiJ8M4GbRcL",
            "position": 1,
            "resourceId": {
              "kind": "youtube#video",
              "videoId": vidId
            }
        }
      }
      let fetchOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post),
      }
      const response = await fetch(fetchString,fetchOptions)
      return await response.json()
    })
  }
```

When calling this method the async/await you will need to update your event listener function to be async

```
document.querySelector("[type=button]").addEventListener("click", async function() {
    //console.log("this was clicked");
    let videoId = document.getElementById('vidUrl').value;
    videoId = videoId.substring(videoId.indexOf('=') + 1);
    console.log(videoId);
    //chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "startFunc", vidId: videoId});
    let request = await addToQueue(videoId);
    console.log(request);
    console.log(request.snippet.title);
    let table = document.querySelector(".table");
    let row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    let title = row.insertCell(0);
    let author = row.insertCell(1);
    title.innerHTML = request.Data.snippet.title;
    author.innerHTML = request.Data.snippet.videoOwnerChannelTitle;
})
```

Also, I have used the new [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax after discussing with OP in comments

Comment: still returns undefined :(

Comment: sorry just noticed all this is in the callback of `chrome.identity`, updated the answer to put a return there as well

Comment: still returning undefined, it was working when I sent it to the background script and then sent it back.

Comment: updated to add how to call the method in your event listener

Comment: Ok, I got it I had to replace the .then with "await" can you update your answer to reflect this so I can choose it as a solution?

Comment: I updated it, I have also added using async await inside the `addToQueue` function

Comment: wait never mind I just tested this with a call to the addToQueue function from the beginning of the script and this worked but when I call it from the other function it still doesn't work.

Comment: add async to the event listener function

Comment: I added async in front of my listener function like this ```document.querySelector("[type=button]").addEventListener("click", async function() {``` and it still returns undefined although it works when I run addToQueue in the beginning of the code.

Comment: have you tried reading through the question this one was mark a duplicate of?

Comment: Yea it's really complex I don't really understand it fully, I hate to be an asshole but I have this assignment due tomorrow and I don't think I have the time to understand this right now, I'll probably just stick with sending the data via sendMessage and I'll try and look into this later this week.